# SQL Developer : Export of the query result don't keep the data_type

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a project where I can't connect directly to the database. I wrote a query that get all the data that I need so I can export them. The result of this SQL query have the great data_type but When I export the result, I choose the `insert` format and at this point all the data_type are switching to string.

Example of the exported data where the number are in the string format wherease in the original database and in the respons of the query, the type is respected  :

```
Insert into MY_TABLE (POSTCODE, NUMBER, ADRESS, CODE, CITY, VALUE) values ('90000', '303', 'HultonLane', '2845', 'BOLTON', '3');
```

Do you know if there is any way to export the data with the same data_type from the original DB?

Thank for your help, if you need more information I will provide them.

Comment: Give us your table and some data. Even just 1 row.

Comment: Updated the question, hope that will be enought, I created the data because I can't share the one I use.

Comment: no, it's not enough, sorry. Please share how MY_TABLE is defined, include the CREATE TABLE command, so I can see the data types involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior (or bug?) exists in e.g. SQL Developer version 19.4, but is **fixed** in 20.2 so - if you're on a lower version, I suggest you upgrade.

---

Here's an example, based on Scott's `DEPT` table where `DEPTNO` column's datatype is `NUMBER`. Result - when this:

```
desc dept;
select /*insert*/ * from dept;
```

is ran as a script - is:

```
Name   Null?    Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
DEPTNO NOT NULL NUMBER       
DNAME           VARCHAR2(20) 
LOC             VARCHAR2(20) 
REM INSERTING into DEPT
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
Insert into DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
Insert into DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
Insert into DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
```

As you can see, all `DEPTNO` values are numbers. In 19.4, you'd have e.g.

```
Insert into DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values ('10','ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
```

(`'10'`, a string).

You don't have to do anything about it; the result is the same regardless you run such a `select` statement, or right-click table name and "Export" data as insert statements.

BTW, our versions match: Mine is 20.2.0.175, build 175.1842.

Comment: Hi, I am already on the version 20.2.0.175 of SQL Developer with the build #175.1842 could you tell me where I should select the behavior that I would like to use? Thanks

Comment: I posted some more info; have a look, please.